# MySQL Preference Pane completely erased my entire /usr/local directory

Tags: mysql

During a one-click uninstall of MySQL via the MySQL preference pane in macOS Mojave, I watched in horror as, one by one, the contents—all directories and files—of my `usr/local` directory disappeared forever. This include Homebrew and all of my `brew` installations/caskets.

In the MySQL Preference Pane, all of the directory settings **explicity** pointed to subdirectories of `usr/local/mysql/...`, so I figured nothing outside of that subdirectory would be deleted. Besides, it did not appear to exist in the first place. I had no idea the entire contents of my `usr/local` directory would be permanently trashed.

Question: Now that I've lost my entire `usr/local` directory, is this behavior cause for concern for others, or is this the expected behavior of MySQL uninstallation via the macOS MySQL Preference Pane?

Could a nefarious symlink have caused this?

Comment: Time to learn shell programming so you can run around the file system and see whether stuff is somewhere else (via a mv, symlink, hard link, or whatever).

Comment: @RickJames  I struggle to see how the MySQL uninstaller could possibly allow the deletion of `usr/local` under any circumstance. It would boggle my mind to find there were a link pointing `usr/local/mysql` to `usr/local`. So maybe this is a question for ux.stackexchange.com.